# X Server error on a console app when I don't have any X Server

Tags: command-line, 19.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

I have Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo on the Windows Subsystem for Linux. I have a command line app called screenfetch (I use the dev version of it because the original displayed an awk error). When I launch it, I get a bunch of errors:

```
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":0.0".
xprop:  unable to open display ':0.0'
xprop:  unable to open display ':0.0'
xprop:  unable to open display ':0.0'
xprop:  unable to open display ':0.0'
```

[image]

Please note that I do NOT have any X-Server apps and I am really disappointed.
Could you find a solution to this weird bug?

Comment: `$DISPLAY` is unset on my WSL - I can't see any good reason why it should be set when there is no Xserver. Maybe start by checking your shell initialization files.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! I deleted $DISPLAY variable from my .bashrc and now it doesn't type any errors.

Comment: @PurpleScientist Please post that comment as an answer and accept that using grey tick. Let me know when you do. I'll upvote the answer. Thanks :)